# How do you define a shorthand route that passes a parameter to the controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, syntax, routes, parameter-passing, shorthand

```
Route::get('/restaurant-detail/{id}', [
// 'as'    => 'restaurant-detail-{id}', // is this legal?
'uses'  => 'RestaurantsController@getRestaurantDetail'
]);
```

How would you get the value of {id} if this is not legal?

Comment: No. named routes are not computed, they are static. this means that you cannot have a named route that has a dynamic property name. Also, why would you need that?

Comment: Why do you want different route name for every record in your database table? Give your route a fixed name and pass the {id} in route function route('restaurant-detail', ['id' => $id])

Comment: for future reference i want to know how to deal with urls that have slugs

Comment: what about urls that have slugs? this isn't very clear what you are trying to solve here.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you want to do?

Comment: @lagbox for linking to posts

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments along with your question you're after a blog setup for retrieving posts from the database using either an `id` or a `slug`. Either can be achieved using the route you've defined:

```
// Routes (web.php)
Route::get('/restaurant-detail/{value}', [
    'as'   => 'restaurant-detail',
    'uses' => 'RestaurantsController@getRestaurantDetail'
]);
```

Here your `getRestaurantDetail` method in the `RestaurantsController` controller receives the `value` from your route as parameter for you to use in your query:

```
// RestaurantsController.php
class RestaurantsController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function getRestaurantDetail($value)
    {
        // First you could check whether you have an id or a slug
        // - Here we'll assume that any string passed is a slug
        $column = is_string($value)? 'slug' : 'id';

        // Now find the post/info using the column
        $post = RestaurantDetail::where($column, $value)->first();

        // Then you can pass your data to a view etc.
        // - Here we simply return it
        return $post;
    }
}
```